# Finding partial derivative $f_x$ of $\ln(x^2y)$ using definition.

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do find partial derivative $f_x$ of $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2y)$  using definition? I know that the answer is $\frac2x$, but I can't see how to get there by using limit $$\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\ln((x+\Delta x)^2y)-\ln(x^2y)}{\Delta x}.$$

Comment: You can start by using the properties of the $\ln$ function. First, $\ln((x+\Delta x)^2y)=\ln(x+\Delta x)^2+\ln y$. Do the same with $\ln (x^2y)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write 
\begin{align}
L&=\frac{\ln((x+\Delta x)^2y))-\ln(x^2y)}{\Delta x} \\
&=\frac{2\ln(x+\Delta x)+\ln(y)-2\ln(x)-\ln(y)}{\Delta x}\\
&=2\left(\frac{\ln(x+\Delta x)-\ln(x)}{\Delta x}\right)
\end{align}

which is recognized as the derivative of $2\ln(x)$ for $\Delta x\rightarrow 0$.